# Can Two Alexa skills have same invocation name?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to use one invocation name but it's already used by another skill in Alexa. I saw few skills have same invocation name.

Comment: Unfortunately invocation names are not unique :( If you have a skill enabled it knows the intent name related to the skill. I'm not sure if you can enable 2 skills with the same name though. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately invocation names are not unique. Every user can choose and activate the skills they want.

See also:

- https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/107549/invocation-name-unique-duplications.html
- And: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/choose-the-invocation-name-for-a-custom-skill.html